# Prevent question from getting downvoted into removal

Tags: discussion

I just ran into this question:
[How many times is this double for-loop executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409945/how-many-times-is-this-double-for-loop-executed/) I find it to be a very interesting question. However, for some reason it already has a whole bunch of downvotes. A lot of the answers don't actually answer this question, giving me the idea a lot of people misunderstand it.

Why is this question getting downvoted so much? And what to do with it?

Comment: As it is, with several upvoted answer, the question will not be removed even if it's closed.

Comment: You joketh/trolleth, surely?   Why would it be so difficult for the OP to try it with some small values, either on paper, or 'for real' with a debugger and single-step, or with logging calls at each loop.  Maybe the poster thinks that someone else should do all that hard work.  and s/he can then just hand in the answer.

Comment: Oh, and it's trash code that modifies the loop vars in the conditionals.  Absolute garbage.  No preofessional/enthusiast programmer would touch it wiith a bargepole.   I would 86-immediate anyone who wrote such code for me.  Their ass and desk woud be empted onto the sidewalk so fast you would not see it happen.  As an example to future users/visitors. it is of negative value.

Comment: I'm glad it was you that ran into it.  I would run from it.

Comment: _"Why is this question getting downvoted so much?"_ Because it's the only appropriate action on that question.

Comment: Teachers are very good at giving students the kind of homework that makes them think but has no practical application.  You volunteered to get him a good grade without him having to think.  It is unlikely to pan out, a teacher is also very good at discovering when a student violates his copyright by republishing his work without consent.  It googles well :)

Comment: "Why is this question getting downvoted so much?" because when I was in school I had to figure it out myself, there was no internet which made it easy to go down the lazy path and bypass having to study, learn and revise. I re-read books numerous times to absorb their knowledge and I spent a great deal of my spare time writing code to try it out. And because I had to, I actually graduated. I very much wish the same upon people who I do catch going down the not-studying path.

Answer (score 8):

> Why is this question getting downvoted so much?

Per the tooltip on downvotes, *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."* You note that:

> A lot of the answers don't actually answer this question, giving me
>   the idea a lot of people misunderstand it.

which certainly suggests that it is unclear, and looking at it certainly doesn't suggest any research was put in, so downvotes do not seem unreasonable. Alternatively, maybe [Tim lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/248731).

---

> And what to do with it?

A few options:

- If you disagree, and think that the question is well-researched, clear and useful as it stands, upvote it.
- If you see a way that it could be improved, either make a comment asking the OP to improve it or suggest an edit doing so yourself.

It's unlikely such a question will be manually deleted and, given that it has multiple answers with upvotes, it won't be automatically removed even if it does get put on-hold.

Comment: poor tim... I hope he built a doghouse where he can sleep when he's locked out of his house, it seems to happen more and more these days

Comment: @Patrice That or people are just blaming Tim more and more rather than admit that a post is actually bad...

Comment: I know where Tim's keys are.  You must raise $1,000,000 within three days.  Delivery instructions to follow.  Fail, and you'll never see those keys again.

Comment: It's deleted now, anyway.

Comment: @BillWoodger that makes my *"It's unlikely such a question will be manually deleted"* look somewhat less than prophetic...

Comment: Yes, which then raises interest as to how, and why. Sort of. If it had a bag of duff answers and was an unhelpful question, then I'm all for it. But, unusual, perhaps.

Comment: "Now" is such a hard word. I always fail to understand it. The question is really not "now" deleted.